# How do I share a USB DVD Writer on a Linux host machine with a virtualised windows guest using Virt-manager?

Tags: linux, windows-10, opensuse, external-drive, virt-manager

I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed, and the windows guest is a Windows 10 instance.

I tried to share the drive by passing through the USB host device but I could not find it on Windows. I looked around and found guides for VirtualBox but performance is important in my case so near-native virtualisation is my only option.

My system (laptop) has an i7 6820HQ and IOMMU so passthrough should not be problematic.

Comment: Have you looked at the content of [this very similar answer here](https://superuser.com/q/956622/167207)?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I don't see why that would be a problem. Virt-manager requires root access to even connect to the VMs that are currently running, so the VM should have no problem accessing the DVD drive.